# Send parameters in URL to .apsx page?

Tags: html, asp.net, url

Let's say there is a page example.com/calendar.aspx and I want to generate a link, showing a month of December there. in source code I found those inputs and values and the link should be example.com/calendar.aspx?calmonth=12. But when I enter that link nothing happens, it's like fresh calendar.aspx page. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You need to look at your query string parameters when it hits your server side method.

Comment: can i look at it in source code of webpage in browser ?

Comment: Do you have access to the server side code?

Comment: no it's not even my website. i'm just user. i can go to browser and see it's source code (html)